# Start loop at specific line of text file in groovy

Tags: groovy, io

I am using groovy and I am trying to have a text file be altered at specific line, without looping through all of the previous lines. Is there a way to state the line of a text file that you want to wish to alter?

For instance

Text file is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I would like to say

```
Line(3) = p
```

and have it change the text file to:

```
1
2
p
4
5
6
```

I DO NOT want to have to do a loop to iterate through the lines to change the value, aka I do not want to use a .eachline {line ->...} method.

Thank you in advance, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You have 3 choices.  1)  Loop through each line till you get to your line of interest.  2)  Load all the lines into memory to jump straight to your line of interest. 3)  Split your huge file into a load of smaller files of known linecount and then do 1 or 2 (this will probably be quicker, as you can jump to closer to where you want to be).  There is no way to just jump to say line 13001 of a 200000 line file (UNLESS each line is exactly the same length).  This is not a limitation of Groovy... The answer would be the same for all languages I can think of

Comment: I am looking to do number 2 without having to load it into memory. I would even be willing to do number 2 with loading it into memory, but even that seems to be impossible without iterating through all of the lines before the target line.

Comment: The thing is text files don't strictly speaking have lines, they just have characters in them that mark the end of the line. So in order to know where line 3 starts, you have to search the file for the character marking the end of the two lines that precede it. Could you elaborate a little on the actual problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps there's a more efficient solution that doesn't require splitting the file into lines in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can skip lines and traverse like this. You could do the skip by using the [Random Access File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in java, but instead of lines you should be specifying the number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `readLines()` on file text. It will store all your lines in a list. To change content at line n, change content at n-1 index on list and then join on list items.
Something like this will do

```
//We can call this the DefaultFileHandler

lineNumberToModify = 3
textToInsert = "p"

line( lineNumberToModify, textToInsert )

def line(num , text){
    list = file.readLines()
    list[num - 1]  = text        
    file.setText(list.join("\n"))
}
```

**EDIT:** For extremely large files, it is better that you have a custom implementation. May be something on the lines of what Tim Yates had suggested in the comment on your question. 
The above readLines() can easily process upto 100000 lines of text within less than a sec. So you can do something like this:

```
if(file size < 10 MB)
   use DefaultFileHandler()
else
   use CustomFileHandler()


//CustomFileHandler

 - Split the large file into buckets of acceptable size.
 - Ex: Bucket 1(1-100000 lines), Bucket 2(100000-200000 lines), etc.
 - if (lineNumberToModify falls in bucket range)
      insert into line in the bucket
```

There is no hard and fast rule to define how you implement your CustomFileHandler as it completely depends on the use case scenario. If you need to do the above operation multiple times on the same file, you can choose to do the complete bucket split first, store them in memory and use the buckets for the following operations. Or if it is a one time operation, you can avoid manipulating all the buckets first but deal with only what you need and process the others later on on-demand basis.

And even within the buckets you can define your own intelligence to speed up your job. Say if you want to insert into 99999 line of a bucket with 1-100000 lines, you can exploit groovy's methods and closures to their fullest,

```
file.readLines().reverse()[1] = "some text"
```

Comment: This method is internally iterating through the lines in the file itself, right? (assuming each line is separated by '\n')  And there is a catch that you might run into an out of memory exception if the text file is considerably huge (say it is a > 1gb log file) as you are loading the whole file into the memory at once.

Comment: You are right but the question seemed to be more about not using manual iteration via eachLine.

Comment: So the idea is to be able to instantly (ish) modify a line of a text file without having to iterate through all of the lines before it. I want to be able to say Modify(line3) and have line3 modified. And although Vamsi did a great job, if I have a 9000000 line text file, it is still going to have to cycle through 899998 to get the second to last line and modify it. Sorry if this isnt making sense. I want to be able to move the line point to the exact line in question.