# Is the reverse() method in groovy merely an abstraction of an iteration?

Tags: loops, groovy, iteration

Based on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624487/start-loop-at-specific-line-of-text-file-in-groovy), the user wanted to access 99999th line of a 100000 lines file without having to iterate using an `eachLine`closure on the first 99998 lines. So, I had suggested that he use

`file.readLines().reverse()[1]` to access the 99999th line of the file.

This is logically appealing to a programmer. However, I was quite doubtful about the intricacy regarding the implementation of this method.

Is the `reverse()` method a mere abstraction of the complete iteration on lines that is hidden from the programmer or is it really as intelligent as to be able to iterate over as less number of lines as possible to reach the required line?

Comment: In general you can't do that with good performance on text files: they are not suited for random access, unless you have some prior knowledge (exact line length, fixed layout, ...). You might be able to optimize *some* operations (getting the last line might be solvable without reading the whole file in most cases), but if you need *true* random access, then don't make it a plain text file (or create an index, if it doesn't change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [from the code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L7506), `reverse()` calls `Collections.reverse` in Java to reverse the list.

However the non-mutating code gives you another option.  Using `listIterator()` you can get an iterator with `hasPrevious` and `previous` to walk back through the list, so if you do:

```
// Our list
def a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
// Get a list iterator pointing at the end
def listIterator = a.listIterator( a.size() )
// Wrap the previous calls in another iterator
def iter = [ hasNext:{ listIterator.hasPrevious() },
             next:{ listIterator.previous() } ] as Iterator
```

We can then do:

```
// Check the value of 1 element from the end of the list
assert iter[ 1 ] == 3
```

However, all of this is an ArrayList under the covers, so it's almost certainly quicker (and easier for the code to be read) if you just do:

```
assert a[ 2 ] == 3
```

Rather than all the reversing.  Though obviously, this would need profiling to make sure I'm right...

Answer (score 0):

According to the "Javadoc" it simply creates a new list in reverse order:

- http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html

Unless I'm missing something, you're correct an it's not that smart to jump cursor immediately.  My understanding is if it's indexed as an Array it can access it directly, but if not has to iterate all over.

---

Alternative might be:

```
file.readLines().last()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer:

```
def a= [1, 2, 3, 4]
def listIterator= a.listIterator(a.size())
def iter= [hasNext: {listIterator.hasPrevious()},
              next: {listIterator.previous()}] as Iterator
assert iter[1] == 3
```

only works in Groovy-1.7.2 and after.

In Groovy-1.7.1, 1.7.0, the 1.7 betas, 1.6, 1.5, and back to 1.0-RC-01, it doesn't find the getAt(1) method call for the proxy. For version 1.0-RC-06 and before, java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Iterator.